# Creating dynamic context menu item in jstree

Tags: contextmenu, jstree

I wanted to create a dynamic context menu based on my server response. The static menu works fine without any issues. The below is my jstree content and it calls customMenu method

```
$("#myList").jstree({
    "core" : {
        "animation" : 0,
        "check_callback" : true,
        //"themes" : "default" ,
            'data': {
                "data": function (node) {
                  return {  "id": node.id };
                }
              }
      },
    "plugins" : [ "search", "contextmenu"], 
    "contextmenu" : { "items" : customMenu }
  });
```

My customMenu function

```
function customMenu(node) {
var menuitems=[];
$.ajax({
    url : "DynamicMenu",
    dataType : 'json',
    data: {menu: node.id, node: node.children.length},
    error : function() {
        alert("Error Occured");
    },
    success : function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            //Want to populate my menu here
        });
    }
});

// The default set of all items. This works fine
menuitems = {
    restartItem: {
        label: "Restart",
        action: function () {
        }
    },
    stopItem: { 
        label: "Stop",
        action: function () {}
    }
};
return menuitems;
```

}

I tried creating a dynamic menu by using below 2 options, but it didnt help.

1. menuitems.push()

   menuitems.push({restartItem: {
                   label: "Restart",
                   action: function () {
                   }
               }});
2. menuitems[index]={mydata}

   menuitems[0] = {restartItem: {
       label: "Restart",
       action: function () {
       }
   }};

Both the above options didn't help ? I will replace the values dynamically based on my ajax response. But first I need one this option to work